# How does one dispose of stolen aircraft?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I'm doing the 6<sup>th</sup> vehicle theft for Rigg in *Saints Row the Thrid*, stealing a Woodpecker from the airport. How do I actually turn it over to him? With the boats and helicopters I just had to get it close to the drop off icon, but that does not seem to work with an airplane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer, it's quite counterintuitive: You must aim the plane at the turn-in icon, then dive straight at it. Hopefully one can do this so that the turn in happens before the horrible plane crash happens.

Comment: You can actually land it instead of crashing on the tiny pier littered with massive boxes if you choose your approach, speed and altitude right, but it's only slightly easier than landing in Top Gun for NES.

Answer (score 0):

Point the plane towards the area. let it glide.

Comment: This answer doesn't add a lot of information, consider elaborating on it with an explanation.